# Is it possible to change the interval on grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, intervals

I would like to change the interval on Grafana. Actually the interval is set to 30s automatically and I couldn't change it. [image]. I have a simple query that qet the value of a metric fom prometheus.

I would like to reduce the interval in order to get more data. I notice that ctrl+z inhance the ineterval automatically. Is there a way to reduce it ?
Thank you

Comment: You can specify lower value for `Min interval`, but this wouldn't guarantee desired outcome: for large panel time range interval will be recalculated.

Comment: But why do you want to do something like this? I believe Grafana usually knows well how much data it needs for visualization.

Comment: Grafana gets one value from prometheus each 30s. A lot of data is lost during this interval. So, I don't receive the real time data

Comment: What do you mean lost? Grafana takes all the needed data from Prometheus, nothing is lost (unless your Prometheus instance forgets recent metrics, but it's hard to believe). As for receiving "real time data" - you would not receive it any way. Prometheus has a scrape interval. Grafana has refresh interval.

Comment: I mean during a specific interval, Prometheus receive a number of data for one metric. But, grafana will take only the last value received on prometheus after this interval. So the other values could not be visualized on grafana because the interval refresh is not enough to get all the data. Thank you for your return

Answer (score 0):

I don't you could do this (nor should).

Grafana is not supposed to be used in this way. It visualizes graph based on available panel width and selected dashboard time range. You can select really small time range, and resolution of shown values will be maximal automatically.

Outside of that best I can suggest for you: use some aggregation over interval Grafana uses as one tick. Something like:

```
sum_over_time(node_cpu_seconds_total[$__interval])
```

And don't forget to add `$__interval` to panel name to see over what range aggregation is taken. Something like `May metric (aggregation over $__interval)`.

But in this case rank of shown values will change drastically with change of dashboard's time range.